# Three.js draggable shape

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm studing this code for [draggable cube](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_draggablecubes)

but I can't understand the reason of create an offset between plane and selected object like in this part of code:

```
function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

            event.preventDefault();

            var vector = new THREE.Vector3( mouse.x, mouse.y, 0.5 );
            projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );

            var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );

            var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects );

            if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

                controls.enabled = false;

                SELECTED = intersects[ 0 ].object;

                var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject( plane );
                offset.copy( intersects[ 0 ].point ).sub( plane.position );// OFFSET

                container.style.cursor = 'move';

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object coordinates when moving are counted concerning coordinates of hit of a mouse on the plane therefore there is a shift. It is possible to do without offset:

```
function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

    ...if ( SELECTED ) {

       var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject( plane );
       SELECTED.position.copy( intersects[ 0 ].point );

   }
}
```

Try, and you will feel a difference. Also you can make on the basis of an this [example](http://alexan0308.github.io/threejs/examples/controls_events_example.html). Look at messages in the console.

```
<script src="js/controls/EventsControls.js"></script>

EventsControls = new EventsControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

EventsControls1.attachEvent( 'dragAndDrop', function () {

    this.container.style.cursor = 'move';
    this.focused.position.y = this.previous.y;

});

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( mesh ); 

EventsControls.attach( mesh );
```

Comment: Is it possible to do the same thing without using plane coordinates but also using : 'mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;'  ?

Comment: Can make SELECTED.position.copy( mouse.x, 0, mouse.y ) or 
SELECTED.position.copy( event.clientX, 0, event.clientY ) ?